# Razor and Ajax: How to reload a table upon successful Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following table that contains Razor code, it is a list of users along with each user's basic details, along with the option to edit or delete each user:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr bgcolor="#FF0000"><th>Username</th><th>User Role</th><th>User Privileges</th><th>Status</th></tr>
        @if (Model.Count() == 0)
        {
            <tr><td colspan="4" class="text-center">No User Accounts</td></tr>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (AppUser user in Model)
            {
                if (!(user.UserName.ToLower().Equals("admin")))
                {
                    <tr>

                        <td>@user.UserName</td>
                        <td>@user.UserRole()</td>
                        <td>@user.UserPrivs()</td>
                        <td>
                            @if (@user.LockedOut)
                            {
                                @:Locked
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                @: Unlocked
                        }
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Admin",
                            new { id = user.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "manageusersform", name = user.UserName }))
                            {
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs editUserBtn"
                                        data-id="@user.Id" name="@user.Id">
                                    Edit
                                </button>

                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                                        type="submit">
                                    Delete
                                </button>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        }
</table>

<div style="text-align:center;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="addnewuser">
      Add New User
</button>
```

As shown above, there is also a button to add a new user. Clicking that brings up a popup form (with id `signupform`) to enter the new user's details, and when that form is submitted, the following javascript gets called:

```
$("form#signupform").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function (res) {
            if (res.status === "success") {

                alert(res.message);

                $(".form-control").val('');

                /*
                reload the table
                */

            }
            else {
                alert(res.message);
            }
        });

    });
```

My goal is to implement the commented `reload the table`, without having to reload the entire page, which is what I am doing now:

```
$("form#signupform").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function (res) {
            if (res.status === "success") {

                alert(res.message);

                $(".form-control").val('');

                /*
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Admin/Index",
                    cache: false,
                    data: {}
                }).done(function (htmlResponse) {
                    $("#tabs-1ua").html(htmlResponse);
                });
                */

            }
            else {
                alert(res.message);
            }
        });

    });
```

Reloading the whole page causes some javascript issues such as the popup not working again, so I am trying to reload just the table now, and would like help.

Thank you.

Comment: i would move the table to a partial view and load / reload it after delete / add / edit / load

Comment: @Emil thanks, got the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create an action method which returns the partial view for the table markup.

```
public ActionResult GetUserTable()
{
  var list = new List<AppUser>();
  // to do : Populate list with data from your data source( user table?)
  return PartialView(list);
}
```

and in the `GetUserTable.cshtml` partial view, put the view code you currently have to render the table

```
@{ Layout = null; }
@model List<AppUser>
<table id="usreList">
  <!-- to do: loop throug model and render table rows) -->
</table>
```

You can use the same action method in your main view as well. Just call this action method

```
@Html.Action("GetUserTable","Users")
<div style="text-align:center;">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="addnewuser">
     Add New User
</button>
```

This will render the user table same as what you currently have.

Now in your ajax success, you can reload your user table by calling this action method asynchronously.

```
if (res.status === "success") {
  $("#usreList").load('/Users/GetUserTable');
}
```

Finally, for the jquery events you wired up to work with the newly injected/dynamic dom elements,you need to use `on` method.

So replace

```
$(".someClass").click(function(e){
  // do something
});
```

with

```
$(document).on("click",".someClass",function(e){
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please explain the last part? I did not change any of my click functions, but things seem to work as expected now. What is the reasoning behind changing it to the `on` method?

Comment: looks like you currently do not have any events wired up using jquery from your table contents. Buf if you do you need to use `on` because `on` works for current and future elements in the 
DOM. Read it here http://api.jquery.com/on/